# How to use UIWebview inside UIAlertView in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am trying to insert UIWebview in UIAlertview as I this tutorial did http://codesofa.com/blog/archive/category/iphone with Table, i have tried webview in code but facing exception and my program in terminationg due to it.

Comment: show us the code and the exception!

Comment: It should work, show us your code and the warning you get so we could see and help.

Comment: I have worked within table instead of using seperately by adding subview in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"WebView" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
[webViewn setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,80,50)];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"google.com"]]];
[alert addSubview:webView];
[webView release];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

try like this.